# Highcharts - column report's height is getting increased when disable and enable the legent item

Tags: highcharts

I have a column report it's height is getting increased when disable and enable the legent item.

`fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/vozq9eq6/

Click the report and drill down first level.
Disable the legend and enable it.
Now the column height is getting increased.

How to disable it?

Comment: Do you mean that axis line is lower (when you hide a serie) ?

Comment: Initially drill down if you see the height of the columns are small. After hide and show the series, the height of the columns are increased. Drill down the project. In the drilled down page hide project and show project. Before and after hide the height of the columns are different.

Comment: OK now I see, so remove extra yAxis and xAxis which are not used, then all seems to be fine.